# Adding binary numbers into vector in for path

Tags: matlab

For example my vector is

```
a = [0 1]
```

I want to add number `0` into vector but in FOR path 3 times. I want to get this vector

```
a = [0 1 0 0 0]
```

Comment: Just checking: by "for path" do you mean "[for](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) loop"?

Comment: Does it have to be a loop and not [concatenating](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) an [array of zeros](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html)?

Comment: What about `[a zeros(1,3)]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are talking about a [`for-loop`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/for.html). This will do what you asked for

```
a = [0 1];
for i=1:3
   a = [a,0];
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a [loop](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/loop-control-statements.html) to do this. This can be accomplished using [concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) and the [`zeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/zeros.html) function.

```
nzeros = 3;
a = [0 1];
a = cat(2, a, zeros(1, nzeros));
% or a = [a zeros(1, nzeros)];
```

Alternatively:

```
nzeros = 3;
a = [0 1];
a(end+nzeros) = 0;
```